# Express - Request.query type definition is ParsedQs. Why is it recursive?

Tags: typescript, express

The type of `request.query` is `ParsedQs` which has the following definition:

```js
interface ParsedQs {
    [key: string]: undefined
        | string
        | string[]
        | ParsedQs
        | ParsedQs[]
}
```

My guess for each types is the following:

- A value is `undefined` when it isn't mentioned in the params.
  For instance: reading `request.query.b` when the params are `?a=1`.
- A value is a `string` when it's mentioned once in the params.
  For instance: reading `request.query.a` when the params are `?a=1`.
- A value is a `string[]` when it's mentioned multiple times in the params.
  For instance: reading `request.query.a` when the params are `?a=1&a=2`.

**But when is a value a `ParsedQs` itself?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query `?a[x]=b&a[y]=c` is parsed into `{"a":{"x":"b","y":"c"}}`.

And `?a[x]=b&a=c` is parsed into `{"a":[{"x":"b"},"c"]}`.

Queries where brackets are nested within brackets, however, are not parsed properly by express: `?a[x[]]=b&a[x[]]=c` is parsed into `{"a[x":["b","c"]}`.

Comment: Thanks, can you edit your answer and add a case for getting `ParsedQs[]` too please.

Comment: I have done that.